# WPF External assemblies name spaces

Tags: .net, wpf, assemblies

I was wondering how the assemblies for third party projects are referenced in XAML.

Sometimes I see

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

and sometimes I see

```
xmlns:tn="clr-namespace:WPFTaskbarNotifier;assembly=WPFTaskbarNotifier"
```

What's the difference between the `URL` style and `clr-namespace` style and when each one is used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XAML loader has to know what assemblies are referenced by elements within the XAML tree.  It uses XML namespaces to find this value.

`clr-namespace` style namespaces are specially formatted in a manner that the XAML loader can locate the assembly and load the types defined within it.  You can reference *any assembly* using this namespace format.  When referencing types *within the same assembly*, you **must** use this format.

the `URL` style is a more conventional XML namespace style.  The URL is [supposed to point to a location where you can get information about the namespace](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/xml/news/xmlnut2_0201.html), such as XSD schemas, etc.  But more often than not they just are 404'd.  You can allow callers who refer to types within your assemblies to use this style of namespace by defining it using the [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx).

Simply drop one per namespace segment within your AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.Herp.com/2012/", "Herp")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.Herp.com/2012/", "Herp.Derp")]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two; they both point to the same assembly.

WPF permits developers to register custom namespaces, using the [`XmlnsDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) attribute at the assembly level. These namespaces then become available to other projects that reference the compiled assembly. You can also use this attribute to merge multiple CLR namespaces together (WPF itself does this), which can simplify the resulting XAML as well as hide your internal project structure from a XAML designer.

But beyond their cosmetic differences, the two namespace strings mean the same thing, and can be used interchangeably. The only restriction here is that you cannot use these custom namespaces *within* the assembly that defines them; they are part of the metadata added to the final assembly, and aren't available to the compiler before then.